# How to get rid of lag when moving a picture box with keyboard

Tags: c#, picturebox, lag

Hi I successfully made a program that moves a picture box by pressing keys, but the movement of the picture box isn't smooth and there is lag when you first start moving the picture box.

Here is my code

```
namespace Imagebox_test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;

        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
            int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

            bool player_left;
            bool player_right;

            player_left = false;
            player_right = false;

            int move_speed;
            move_speed = 10;

            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.A:
                    player_right = false;
                    player_left = true;
                    break;
                case Keys.D:
                    player_right = true;
                    break;
            }

            if (player_left == true) x -= move_speed; 
            if (player_right == true) x += move_speed;

            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
```

}

How can I get rid of this lag and make the movement smoother?

Help much appreciated.

Comment: I would not use PictureBox for making a game, they are very slow. The usual approach if you want to make a game in Winforms is to override `OnDraw` of the forum. However if you are wanting to do this for more than just a hobby project I would reccomend finding a game engine instead of using winforms. Unity is easy to use, free, and can be used with [2D sprite based games](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial).

Comment: Do you maybe mean the lag before the keyboard repeat delay is over? See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172621/how-can-i-get-rid-of-character-repeat-delay-in-c) for a suggestion how to avoid it. Or is it your acceleration (+-1) is too small? Do change your variables to float (e.g. +-1.5f) and only use ints for the location!! Also: maybe introduce an accelration variable that also can grow..

Comment: And, no, PictureBoxes are not really slow unless they are really big.. Painting stuff yourself is a lot more flexible, though! And game programming in winforms is always extremely limited, to put it mildly

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29957353/5045688).