# Pause after first keypress, synchronous solution

Tags: c#

There is the whole super simple C# console app here:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int left = 0;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(++left, 0);
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo stisknutaKlavesa = Console.ReadKey(true);

                if (stisknutaKlavesa.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(++left, 0);
                    Console.Write("#");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Description: When I press RIGHT KEY (and hold it!!) it quickly writes one hash, then there is a pause, and then it fluently keeps writting another hashes further.

How can I get rid of that pause? I have been dealing with identical problem in one of my winform app, but for simplicity I posted it in this console application here.

I have found some answers about this topic but all of them were about javascript (jquery) and i did not understand how to apply it on this my c# project.

And i do not want to resolve it in asynchronous way either. Is there such a solution, please?

[image]

Comment: By pause do you mean waiting for input as in `Console.ReadKey` ?

Comment: In fact i have no idea what that pause is. Because it only comes between first and second hash and there is no other waiting then. Why it does not wait later when i press right arrow and hold it?

Comment: Do you mean the "keyboard repeat delay" between a key press being interpreted as a single press or repeat if you hold it down? If so, it's a system wide setting, there's another question here with an answer about working around it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172621/how-can-i-get-rid-of-character-repeat-delay-in-c

Comment: Thanks Steve! I will explore it but even now i see that the correct answer is using Timer, which (I guess) means it it not sync. But thanks for that link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes from the way that the windows console (and most other text-based inputs in Windows and other environments) behaves. If you put your cursor on any text input (like your browser's address bar, for instance), and press and hold an arrow key, you will see it move once, pause, and then start moving repeatedly with a much shorter pause.

In effect, your console's `ReadKey` registers keypresses based on some predefined behaviors of the operating system.

If you want to be able to detect and respond to someone holding a key down, you'll need to use a medium that gives you more low-level access to events like `keydown` and `keyup`. Something like Windows Forms, WPF, Unity... pretty much anything that's not `Console`.

Furthermore, if you want to respond to those key-down and key-up events using timing that's different from how the system treats those events, you'll have to create your own timing mechanism, and only use those events to help you know when things have changed. Examples of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1172644/120955) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29957353/120955).

If you're trying to make something akin to a video game, you might consider looking into libraries that are specifically designed for these use cases, like Unity3D.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. The same behaviour i have in winform when i catch keydown event. Really identical behaviour. Just for simplicity i put it here in a console app project.

Comment: @user7968180: You are correct. I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: So synchronous solution does not exist. Ok.